# How to cache/replay re-auth requests? RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to implement some fallback re-auth mechanism when my requests to the server receive a 401. To do it I used **onErrorResumeNext()**, so that whenever an error occurs I can try the re authentication (if that possible).

For example

```
fun streamFromServerObservable(): Observable<ServerData> {
  ...
}

fun requestFromServer() {
   streamFromServerObservable
       .onErrorResumeNext(ReAuthenticator.reAuthenticateAndRetry(streamFromServerObservable))
}
```

fun
The method reAuthenticateAndRetry is below:

```
fun <T> reAuthenticateAndRetry(toBeResumed: Observable<T>): Func1<Throwable, Observable<T>> {
        return Func1 {
            if (isAuthenticationError(it)) {
                return@Func1 reAuthenticate().flatMap { toBeResumed }
            }

            Observable.error(it)
        }
    }

fun reAuthenticate() : Observable<User> {
   return  api.login()
}
```

With this kind of scenario things are working, however I wanted to implement this in way such that if there were multiple failed requests by unauthorization I could use the answer of the first re-auth request to feed the others.

I thought in using the **replay** operator on the Observable that **reAuthenticate()** returns but whenever the reAuth stops working as if it stopped streaming events.

I am aware of the **cache* operator, however I wanted to replay the reAuth answers for a short period time (instead of using a capacity)

Comment: Have you tried using the retry / retryWhen operators?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the opposite @Will ! I want to stop repeated the requests (this is, if im doing a reauth request I just want to replay the last response if it was done in a small window of time)

Comment: If I understood you right, how about using `lift()` with custom `Operator`? You can catch any `Throwable` there, than pass it to needed handler and unsubscribe from observable if it's critical exception